# Как правильно задать background для блока, подробней на фото

Tags: html, css

Надо поставить такой же фон как указано в макете

[image]

Стили:

```css
.main-block {
  &__container {
    padding: rem(140) rem(15) 0 rem(15);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
  }
  &__image {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 48%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    justify-content: end;
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    &::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background: radial-gradient(48.48% 50% at 50% 50%, #6E40F2 0%, rgba(110, 64, 242, 0) 100%);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
  &__content {
    flex: 0 1 52%;
    padding: 0 0 0 rem(39);
  }
  &__title {}
  &__text {}
  &__button {}
  &__icons {}
}
```

```html
<main class="page">
<section class="page__main main-block">
  <div class="main-block__container">
    <div class="main-block__image">
      <img src="img/main/ellipse.svg" alt="ellipse">
    </div>
    <div class="main-block__content">
      <h1 class="main-block__title title">
        Exchange your cryptocurrency with <span> Change crypto coin</span>
      </h1>
      <div class="main-block__text text">
        You will not find better prices than ours anywhere, so we suggest you start earning on cryptocurrency with us
      </div>
      <div class="main-block__button button">Change crypto</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-block__icons icons-main-block">
    <div class="icons-main-block__item icons-main-block__item_1"></div>
    <div class="icons-main-block__item icons-main-block__item_2"></div>
    <div class="icons-main-block__item icons-main-block__item_3"></div>
  </div>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Единственное место, где в приведенном коде указан бэкграунд, это

    background: radial-gradient(48.48% 50% at...

Видимо там и вставить нужный

Comment: Блок с картинкой абсолютный должен быть и с градиентом тоже